# Google calendar Api v3 and OAuth2 ServiceAccountCredential in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I´m trying to connect to Googels API using the Service Account Credential. I have created a Service Account in the Googles developers console I also have done all the settings in the Google Apps domain account, but it does not work. When I try to get an event in my Google calender I just get the following message. Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error: "access_denied" Description: "Requested Client Not Authorized." Uri: ""

Please, what am I doing wrong?

This is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serviceAccountEmail = ".....@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        string keyFilePath = @"c:\nameName.p12";
        string  userEmail = "name.name@domain.com";
        string[] scopes = new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly }; 

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "secret", X--------509rageFlags&???.Exportable);
        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            User = userEmail,
            Scopes = scopes
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        var calService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApplicationName = "Test calendar",
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        });

        string eventid = "_60q30c1g60o0s46chk74oj0dhh64rj8ca16p138dpo74ojedhh8oq34dq4";

        Event myEvent = calService.Events.Get(userEmail, eventid).Execute();
        Literal1.Text = myEvent.Summary;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application accesses user data, the service account that you created needs to be granted access to the Google Apps domain’s user data that you want to access.

The following steps must be performed by an administrator of the Google Apps domain: Go to your Google Apps domain’s Admin console.

Select Security from the list of controls. If you don't see Security listed, select More     controls from the gray bar at the bottom of the page, then select Security from the list of controls.

Select Advanced settings from the list of options.

Select Manage third party OAuth Client access in the Authentication section.

In the Client name field enter the service account's Client ID.

In the One or More API Scopes field enter the list of scopes that your application should be granted access to. For example if you need domain-wide access to the Google Drive API and the Google Calendar API enter: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Click Authorize.

Also, please check whether you have included all the scopes in your code which your application is trying to access.

Let me know if you still see the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer SGC, but I have done all the settings in our Google Apps domain account.  I have followed all the steps in Google's manual on https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount I have also checked so that is the calendar we have access to in the scops. Could it be something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error. You were right the SGC. I have in my code entered scops for CalendarService.Scope.Calendar and CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly.
But in our administrator console for Google Apps domain, I have just entered the access to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar. I must also add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly. It's obvious, stupid me.

Thanks SGC